# Django Crispy Form Shows {'id': ['This field is required.']}

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms, inline-formset

I'm receiving the following error when I click the save button on my inline formset using Crispy Forms:

[{'id': ['This field is required.']}, {'id': ['This field is required.']}, {'id': ['This field is required.']}, {}, {}]

The formset is bound but not valid because of the missing id, but I'm not sure how to set the id.

```
#views.py
    class View(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
        template_name = "example.html"
        MyFormSet = modelformset_factory(
            model=MyModel,
            form=MyModelForm,
            formset=MyModelFormset,
            can_delete=True,
            extra=1,
            fields=('field_1','field_2', ))

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            my_formset = self.MyFormSet()
            context['my_formset'] = MyModel.objects.all().order_by('field_1')
            return context

        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            my_formset = self.MyFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if my_formset.is_valid():
                try:
                    my_formset.save()
                except:
                    messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Cannot delete: this parent has a child 1 !')
            else:
                context = self.get_context_data()
                context['my_formset'] = my_formset
                return render(request, self.template_name, context)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy("example"))

#forms.py
    class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = MyModel
            fields = ['field_1', 'field_2']


        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.helper = FormHelper()
            self.helper.form_tag = False
            self.helper.layout = Layout(
                Row(
                    Column('field_1'),
                    Column('field_2'),
                    Column('DELETE'),
                )
            )



#template
    <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">{% csrf_token %}        
        {{ my_formset.management_form|crispy }}
        {% for form in my_formset.forms %}
            {% crispy form form.helper %}                            
        {% endfor %}
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

When rendering forms with layouts as part of formset, you must set render_hidden_fields = true. See more notes in the documentation.

https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/form_helper.html